# calling function from within class with array_walk_recursive

Tags: php, arrays, class, function, recursion

This is a simplified version of a class that I have in php:

```
class someClass {
   public function edit_array($array) {
      array_walk_recursive($array, 'edit_value');
   }
   public function edit_value(&$value) {
      //edit the value 
   }
}
```

Now sending the name of the function from within the class to array_walk_recursive obviously does not work. However, is there a work around other than recreating array_walk_recursive using a loop (I'll save that as my last resort)? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

the function needs to be referenced staticly. I used this code with success:

```
<?php

class someClass {
   public function edit_array($array) {
      array_walk_recursive($array, 'someClass::edit_value');
   }
   public static function edit_value(&$value) {
      echo $value; 
   }
}

$obj = new SomeClass();

$obj->edit_array(array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7));
```

Comment: just to keep in mind --- 
namespace someNamespace;
then 
array_walk_recursive($array, '\someNamespace\someClass::edit_value');

Answer (score 31):

Your methods are not defined as static so I'll assume you are instantiating. In that case, you can pass `$this`:

```
public function edit_array($array) {
    array_walk_recursive($array, array($this, 'edit_value'));
}
```

Comment: This is the better answer. Accepted answer doesn't really answer the question, just provides an alternative for static classes, which sometimes are not desirable.

Comment: Nice sollution!

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
class someClass {
   static public function edit_array($array) {
      array_walk_recursive($array, array(__CLASS__,'edit_value'));
   }
   static public function edit_value(&$value) {
      //edit the value 
   }
}
```

**NB:** I used `__CLASS__` so that changing class name doesn't hinder execution. You could have used `"someClass"` instead as well.

Or in case of instances:

```
class someClass {
   public function edit_array($array) {
      array_walk_recursive($array, array($this,'edit_value'));
   }
   public function edit_value(&$value) {
      //edit the value 
   }
}
```

Comment: __CLASS__ is only necessary if you're trying to call it statically.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it inline..

```
array_walk_recursive($myArray, function (&$item){
   $item = mb_convert_encoding($item, 'UTF-8');
});
```